# How to set nunit category with predefined strings/Dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, nunit

I have test classes in which I set categories for each tests. I used the same set of categories, but the combination for each test is different.
I wonder if there is an option of setting the category "string" from predefined Dictionary<CatergoryEnum, string>

instead of:

```
[Test]
[Category("Regression")]
```

Do like that:

```
[Test]
[Category(CategoryDict[CategoryEnum.Regression])]


enum CategoryEnum
{
  Regression
}
```

CategoryDict - C# dictionary

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be a `Dictionary`, only things evaluated during compile time are allowed in the annotations' arguments. You could use `const` strings, for example like this:

```
public class Categories
{
    public const string Regression = nameof(Regression);
    public const string AnotherCategory = "Different name than property name";
}

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    [Category(Categories.Regression)]
    public void GetEmployees_Should_NotReturnAnyNulls()
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @user2304318 I'm glad! Since it's exactly what you looked for, could you mark the answer as accepted?